# jackson deserializer - get model field annotations list

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson, deserialization

I'm working on a java spring mvc project. I have created `CustomObjectMapper` class that extends `ObjectMapper` form jackson. Also I set `CustomObjectMapper` in the spring configuration, so every time jackson wants to `serialize` or `deserialize`, my `CustomObjectMapper` works and everything is right. But I have one problem:

I have created a custom annotation `@AllowHtml` and I have put it on top of some `String` fields in my model. Also I have created a `JsonDeserializerString` class in this way:

```
public class JsonDeserializerString extends JsonDeserializer<String>{

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        return jp.getText();
    }

}
```

And I set this deserializer in my `CustomObjectMapper` in this way:

```
@Component
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
     public CustomObjectMapper(){
         SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
         module.addDeserializer(String.class, new JsonDeserializerString());
         this.registerModule(module);
     }
}
```

This works as expected and when a user submit a form, every string fields deserialize with `JsonDeserializerString`. But I want to **get field annotations in the deserializer.**. In fact, I want to, If a string field has a certain annotation in the model, do some logics. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

Your deserializer could implement ContextualDeserializer and extract the property annotations. You could store it in a private property and reuse it while deserializing the String.

**Example:**

```
public class EmbeddedDeserializer 
    extends JsonDeserializer<Object> 
    implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private Annotation[] annotations;

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(final DeserializationContext ctxt, 
        final BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {

        annotations = property.getType().getRawClass().getAnnotations();

        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(final JsonParser jsonParser, 
        final DeserializationContext context) 
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

            if (annotations contains Xxxx) { ... }
        }
}
```

I hope it helps.